# Lists and indices in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a  list:

```
food_list=["chicken", "mixed veggies", "greens", "beans", "corn", "cooking oil"]
```

I can access each food item by their positions and print something, like this:

```
"You do have food, your options are {} or {} or {} or {}".format(
    food_list[0], food_list[1],  food_list[3], food_list[4]
)
```

(without including the last item: 'cooking oil')

However, if the length of  the list is altered in any way, this will give an index (out of range) error.

How do I get items in the list, put them within a sentence as above without getting any errors if the list length is altered?

Comment: That would only have errors if the list had fewer than four items - what _do_ you want to happen in that case?

Comment: You need to somehow iterate through all the items you want. Have you looked into iteration yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in one line. for e.g.

```
food_list=["chicken", "mixed veggies", "greens", "beans", "corn", "cooking oil"]
"You do have food, your options are {}".format(" or ".join(food_list[:-1]))
```

Output:

> You do have food, your options are chicken or mixed veggies or greens or beans or corn

ps: this will also exclude the last food item in the list.

Comment: I think this answer was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
options = " or ".join(food_list)
```

Comment: cool, but I want the whole list  except the last food item, so I guess I could use....food_list[:-1] ...I guess

Answer (score 0):

Here, you want to use something like a simple for-loop:

```
string = "You do have food, your options are "
for food in food_list:
   string += food + " or "
string = string[:-3]
print(string)
```

Here, you remove the last few characters to remove the last "or", while dynamically adding each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```
food_list=["chicken", "mixed veggies", "greens", "beans", "corn", "cooking oil"]
"You do have food, your options are {}".format(" or ".join(food_list))
```

There would be plenty of ways to do what you're asking for.

### join

join, joins a containers each element into a string:

```
",".join(["mohammad", "Shameoni", "Niaei"])
#'mohammad,Shameoni,Niaei'
```

### loops

You can easily loop through the iterable and append them into a string.

```
my_string = ""
for element in ["mohammad", "Shameoni", "Niaei"]:
    my_string += element + ","

my_string = my_string[:-1]
#'mohammad,Shameoni,Niaei'
```

Use one of above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fstring.

```
food_list=["chicken", "mixed veggies", "greens", "beans", "corn", "cooking oil"]
print(f"You do have food, your options are {food_list[0]} or {food_list[1]} or {food_list[3]} or {food_list[4]}")
```